# Tabularx p column broken vertical line with manual linebreak

Tags: pdftex, tabularx

I have a table that uses tabularx with some p columns and some X columns. In the p columns I manually added line breaks. Everything is fine except the fact that the vertical lines that divide the columns from each other are broken at the places where I added the line breaks.
What is the best way to fix this?
This MWE shows the problem:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, mode=presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{columns} \column{\dimexpr\paperwidth-10pt} \scriptsize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{0.24\textwidth}|p{0.09\textwidth}|X|X|p{0.09\textwidth}|X|X|}
    \hline
    \textbf{settings} & some result & some result & some result & some result & some result & some result \\ \hline
    \textbf{cat1:} bla & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \textbf{cat1:} lala & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \textbf{cat1:} bla,\\ \textbf{cat2:} some value & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \textbf{cat1:} bla,\\ \textbf{cat2:} some value,\\ \textbf{cat3:} other value & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\newline` instead of `\\`, if you mean it.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, mode=presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{columns} \column{\dimexpr\paperwidth-10pt} \scriptsize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{0.24\textwidth}|p{0.09\textwidth}|X|X|p{0.09\textwidth}|X|X|}
    \hline
    \textbf{settings} & some result & some result & some result & some result & some result & some result \\ \hline
    \textbf{cat1:} bla & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \textbf{cat1:} lala & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \textbf{cat1:} bla,\newline \textbf{cat2:} some value & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \textbf{cat1:} bla,\newline \textbf{cat2:} some value,\newline \textbf{cat3:} other value & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or define a more versatile macro:

```
\newcommand{\mycell}[2][t]{%
\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}
#2
\end{tabular}
}
%% #1 - alignment, t, or c or b, #2 - content.
```

so that you can even control the vertical alignment.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, mode=presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand{\mycell}[2][t]{%
\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}
#2
\end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\begin{columns} \column{\dimexpr\paperwidth-10pt} \scriptsize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{0.24\textwidth}|p{0.09\textwidth}|X|X|p{0.09\textwidth}|X|X|}
    \hline
    \textbf{settings} & some result & some result & some result & some result & some result & some result \\ \hline
    \textbf{cat1:} bla & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \textbf{cat1:} lala & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \mycell{\textbf{cat1:} bla,\\ \textbf{cat2:} some value} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \mycell[c]{\textbf{cat1:} bla,\\ \textbf{cat2:} some value,\\ \textbf{cat3:} other value} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh, that hyphenated word in the headings is unattractive, especially since in the columns with a different format than `X`, the space before "re-" is wider

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you, using \newline did the trick. Can you explain why? Also, I don't understand your macro. Can you give more explanation to that?

Comment: @BarbaraBeeton My real table looks different and those values are perfect for it. The table I posted here is just an example.

Comment: @anjuta: Inside tabular ` \\ ` is meant for row breaking. If you use it inside the cell like you did, it does only bad. i.e., you are creating 2 extra rows with only one cell, so no vertical lines are drawn.So we use the equivalent, `\newline` which means new line.

Comment: @anjuta: The new macro is a simple `tabular` with a single `l` column. I used `@{}` to remove the padding on both sides of this column. And `#1` specifies the alignment point of the tabular.